# Solving logical matrix

Tags: puzzle

Can anyone explain why the selected option in the attached image is the correct one?
(Need it for uni entrance test)

[Logical Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ksYC.png)

Comment: Do your own entrance exam, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the dots flips, the other rotates.